# Eliminate margins while rendering a pdf with phantomJS

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, d3.js, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to render an html web page with D3 charts to a PDF report.The report looks near perfect after I made some changes to rasterize.js. However, no matter what I change, I've not been able to eliminate the left and right margins completely.Could someone suggest any modifications to raterize.js to remove these margins altogether. My changes to the file are as below:-

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 595, height: 842 };   //**A4**
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {
    size = system.args[3].split('*');
    page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '-150px' }
                                       : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '-4cm' }; //**Swapnil:- added a negative margin to utilize the entire width of the canvas. (Reduces the margins but does not eliminate them completely)**
} else if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[3].substr(-2) === "px") {
    size = system.args[3].split('*');
    if (size.length === 2) {
        pageWidth = parseInt(size[0], 10);
        pageHeight = parseInt(size[1], 10);
        page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
    } else {
        console.log("size:", system.args[3]);
        pageWidth = parseInt(system.args[3], 10);
        pageHeight = parseInt(pageWidth * 3/4, 10); // it's as good an assumption as any
        console.log ("pageHeight:",pageHeight);
        page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
    }
}
if (system.args.length > 4) {
    page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
}
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 20000);  // **Swapnil:- increased time out to ensure all the charts load perfectly**
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all set the margins to 0:

```
page.paperSize = {
    // ...
    margin: { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }
};
```

Next you need to make sure the pdf pagesize is exactly the size of your content. You can do that either ...

... by setting the width according to the width of your rendered page in pixels (manually calculate the height for whatever format you use) and adjust for a potential difference in dpi

or

... by playing around with the zoom until the page fits perfectly.

It's a lot of fiddling either way. Phantomjs can render a page perfectly but it's not easy.

Comment: can you please explain how to set the width or adjust the zoom please. Because I am trying so hard to find the width of the page dynamically, because the content width varies everytime